# How do you find the radius with only the slant height? Please show work.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The radius of the circle is 12cm, it is then made into a cone

**Question:**

A cone is made by joining the straight edges and securing them with tape.  Calculate the angle of inclination, to the nearest tenth of a degree, for the sides of the cone.

[image: cone_formation]

**Answer:**

Angle of inclination is 41.4 degree.

Comment: I think you need to remove a sector from the circle before you can make a cone out of it.

Comment: Do you know formula for area of a circle, area of a sector, circumference of a circle, lateral surface area of a cone, Pythagoras theorem and $\cos \theta$

Answer (score 2):

We need to find the perimeter of the circle sector first:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $l$ denote the slant height of the cone.  Let $r$ denote the radius of the cone.  Let $\varphi$ denote the angle of the sector of the circle.  Let $\theta$ denote the angle of inclination.

Strategy:

1. The lateral surface area of the cone is equal to the area of the sector.  The lateral surface area of the cone is 
   $$L = \pi rl$$
   Since the sector has radius $l$, its area is 
   $$A = \frac{\varphi}{360^\circ} \pi l^2$$
   where $\varphi$ is measured in degrees.  Since $l$ is given, you can set $L = A$ to solve for $r$.
2. To determine the angle of inclination, solve the equation $$\cos\theta = \frac{r}{l}$$ for $\theta$.